# What is the function/purpose of \!\(...\) in Graphics?

Tags: graphics, output-formatting, text, input-forms

In `Graphics`, we input the `Text` form `"\!\(10m prize\)"`, but it outputs "10 *m* prize":

```
 Graphics[{Text["\!\(10m prize\)", {2, 2}]}, PlotRange -> {{0, 4}, {0, 4}}]
```

> [image]

If we input the `Text` form `"10m prize"`, then we get "10m prize":

```
Graphics[{Text["10m prize", {2, 2}]}, PlotRange -> {{0, 4}, {0, 4}}]
```

> [image]

**My question: what is the function/purpose of \!\(...\)?**

Comment: Relevant documentation is found [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/TextualInputAndOutput.html#28564)

Comment: The first is a string representation of boxes, equivalent to `FullForm@ToExpression["\!\(10m prize\)"]`

Answer (score 3):

As [Michael E2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/4999/michael-e2) explains in the comments, in the first case you have a [string representation of boxes](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/TextualInputAndOutput.html#28564). You can get the expression they represent using `ToExpression`:

```
ToExpression["\!\(10m prize\)", StandardForm, HoldForm]
% // TraditionalForm
```

[image: screesnhot]

In `Graphics` by default expressions are formatted in `TraditionalForm`, hence the formatting you notice.

The second case is just a simple `String`, which is shown "as is".

The linked [Documentation chapter](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/TextualInputAndOutput.html#28564) clearly explains the purpose of the `\!\(...\)` syntax.